# Which $TERM to use to have both 256 colors and mouse move events in python curses?

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, xterm, python-curses

Currently if I set the TERM environment variable to 'xterm-1003' I can get mouse move events but I get crappy colors and curses.can_change_color() == False

```
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm-1003'
...
curses.mousemask(curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS | curses.REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)
...
while True:
    event = screen.getch()
    if event == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        # I get nice events whenever I move the mouse (no click required)
        _, mx, my, _, _ = curses.getmouse()
```

and if I set the TERM env var to 'xterm-256color' I get a nice color palette plus curses.can_change_color() == True, however I do not receive mouse events unless I click a button!

```
>ls /usr/share/terminfo/x/
```

reports

```
xfce           xterm-256color  xterm-hp      xterm-r5     xterm-xf86-v32   xterm-xfree86
xterm          xterm-88color   xterm-new     xterm-r6     xterm-xf86-v33   xterm-xi
xterm-1002     xterm-8bit      xterm-nic     xterm-sco    xterm-xf86-v333  xterms
xterm-1003     xterm-basic     xterm-noapp   xterm-sun    xterm-xf86-v40
xterm-16color  xterm-bold      xterm-old     xterm-vt220  xterm-xf86-v43
xterm-24       xterm-color     xterm-pcolor  xterm-vt52   xterm-xf86-v44
```

None of the ones I tried seem to support both curses.can_change_color() == True and mouse move events. Is there a way I can get both of them via setting an appropriate $TERM value or some other way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

You can always make your own, using [infocmp](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) (to show the contents of an entry), and [tic](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html) (to compile an entry).  If you do not have permission to write in the system area, it goes to $HOME/.terminfo

Start by comparing [xterm-1003](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-1003) and [xterm-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color):

```
> infocmp -x xterm-1003 xterm-256color
comparing xterm-1003 to xterm-256color.
    comparing booleans.
        ccc: F:T.
    comparing numbers.
        colors: 8, 256.
        pairs: 64, 32767.
    comparing strings.
        initc: NULL, '\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\'.
        setab: '\E[4%p1%dm', '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m'.
        setaf: '\E[3%p1%dm', '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m'.
        setb: '\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m', NULL.
        setf: '\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m', NULL.
        XM: '\E[?1003%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;', NULL.
```

Essentially, all you are interested in is adding the `XM` capability to a copy of `xterm-256color`.

So...

1. `infocmp -x xterm-256color >foo`
2. edit `foo`, adding the `XM` string
3. `tic -x foo`

The "-x" option is needed for `tic` to compile the `XM` capability, which is an *extended* (user-defined) capability which ncurses happens to recognize as noted in comments for the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_X_T_E_R_M__Extensions_).

Comment: Why was this answer never accepted? I have the exact issue (albeit with another programming language) and it solves problem, is detailed, and links to references for research.

Answer (score 2):

Try [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809709/5232323), it's simple and no impact to the system.

```
curses.mousemask(curses.REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)
print('\033[?1003h') # enable mouse tracking with the XTERM API
```

**Note that the print must appear after the mousemask() is called.**

Comment: ...but it's not what OP asked for (button-event versus any-event)

Comment: by the way - without an `fflush(stdout)`, this won't work very well (it happens to work on MacOS because the ncurses version is very old).

Answer (score 1):

The problem: **Mouse position reported even when no mouse button held down.**

This answer is intended to be an extension of the other [answer here posted by Thomas Dickey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29023361/7915759). Using the links provided and basic steps, I managed to find an XM string that gave me the mouse behavior I wanted.

The problem I had with the XM string in the other answer is the mouse position was reported even when no mouse button was held down. I wanted mouse position only when a mouse button was down. In other words, I wanted "mouse drag" events. The constant reporting might be good for implementing a "mouse hover" feature, but I didn't need that so all the extra reporting was just causing wasted cycles in the app's event loop.

The steps I took to find the right XM string were:

1. Create a 'foo' file as described in the other answer: `infocmp -x xterm-256color > foo`
2. Take the text from the [terminal database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_X_T_E_R_M__Extensions_) link and extract all the XM strings (provided below).
3. Add one of the XM strings to my copy of 'foo' and issue `tic -x foo` (the new config is immediately active).
4. Run my program to see if the mouse position behaved as wanted.
5. If the behavior was different, go back to step 3 and try the next string.

The (commented out) XM strings as extracted from the "terminal database" link:

```
#    XM=\E[?9%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    XM=\E[?9%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    xm=\E[M%p3%' '%+%c%p2%'!'%+%c%p1%'!'%+%c,
#    XM=\E[?1000%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    xm=\E[M%?%p4%t%p3%e%{3}%;%'\s'%+%c%p2%'!'%+%c%p1%'!'%+%c,
#    XM=\E[?1001%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    XM=\E[?1002%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    XM=\E[?1003%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    XM=\E[?1005;1000%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    xm=\E[M%?%p4%t3%e%p3%'\s'%+%c%;%p2%'!'%+%u%p1%'!'%+%u,
#    XM=\E[?1006;1000%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
#    xm=\E[<%i%p3%d;%p1%d;%p2%d;%?%p4%tM%em%;,
```

The string that worked for my Ubuntu 20 sytem's bash terminal was:

```
    XM=\E[?1002%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
```

I anticipate some extra future work enabling this behavior on other systems when my app is nearly ready for distribution.

Another potential problem is this hack may affect bash behavior generally - not just when my app is running in a bash terminal. Maybe a better solution would be not to tweak the `xterm-256color` file, but create a custom file of another name unlikely to be confused with the standard files. Then in my application set the `TERM` environment variable to it before initiating `curses`.

```py
    os.environ['TERM'] = 'mouse-tweaked-xterm-256color'
    curses.wrapper(start_my_app)
```

Update: The new `xterm-256color` file produced by `tic` was located on my system under `${HOME}/.terminfo/x/`. I changed its name and implemented the above code to set `TERM` in the application.