# how to enable mouse movement events in curses

Tags: python, python-curses, terminfo

How do I enable mouse movement events in curses?

I found this [Mouse movement events in NCurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462850/mouse-movement-events-in-ncurses), [Xterm Control Sequences](https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html) and [ncurses_mouse_movement](https://gist.github.com/sylt/93d3f7b77e7f3a881603) but I don't understand from that, how to enable mouse movement events in python-curses. I figure it has something to do with TERM=xterm-1003 but I don't know how to set that in python-curses.

this is what I did to enable any mouse events:

```
curses.mousemask(curses.REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION | curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS)
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303971/how-to-enable-mouse-movement-events-in-python-curses

Comment: I know barman, an answer to any of those posts would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a pretty old question and the OP might not need it anymore, but I'm leaving it here for anyone who stumbles upon this question after hours of googling and head scratching:

```py
import curses

def main(win:curses.window):
    win.clear()
    win.nodelay(True)
    curses.mousemask(curses.REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)
    print('\033[?1003h') # enable mouse tracking with the XTERM API
    # https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking

    while True:
        ch=win.getch()
        if ch==curses.KEY_MOUSE:
            win.clear()
            win.addstr(0,0,str(curses.getmouse()[1:3]))
            win.refresh()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

The most important line here is the `print('\033[?1003h')`, which enables the mouse position reporting to the program, while the `mousemask` enables curses to interpret the input from the terminal. Note that the `print` must appear after the `mousemask()` is called.

Tested on macOS 10.14.6 with iTerm2. There is no tweak to the terminfo.

Comment: Use `print('\033[?1003l')`, i.e. lower case L, to stop the terminal reporting mouse position when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work. On Ubuntu it worked by simply setting `TERM=screen-256color`, but on OSX I had to edit a terminfo file, using the instructions here:

[Which $TERM to use to have both 256 colors and mouse move events in python curses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020638/which-term-to-use-to-have-both-256-colors-and-mouse-move-events-in-python-curse)

but on my system the format was different so I added the line:

`XM=\E[?1003%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,`

to my terminfo. To test it, I used this Python code (note `screen.keypad(1)` is very necessary, otherwise mouse events cause `getch` to return escape key codes).

```
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
screen.keypad(1)
curses.curs_set(0)
curses.mousemask(curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS | curses.REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)
curses.flushinp()
curses.noecho()
screen.clear()

while True:
    key = screen.getch()
    screen.clear()
    screen.addstr(0, 0, 'key: {}'.format(key))
    if key == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        _, x, y, _, button = curses.getmouse()
        screen.addstr(1, 0, 'x, y, button = {}, {}, {}'.format(x, y, button))
    elif key == 27:
        break

curses.endwin()
curses.flushinp()
```

Comment: Any way to get it to work on Windows console? Python's `curses` only reports mouse events on my Windows when mouse is pressed or released, but not moved. Is there any similar terminal setup method on Windows?

Comment: I can get the position of mouse by invoking winapi's `ReadConsoleInput` in masm. So maybe I can do it using `ctypes`. But it would be dirty...